# Should most brahmins today be considered as shudras?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mahabharata, puranas

Since most brahmins particularly those living in urban areas today don't follow the duties of a brahmin , should they be considered as shudras ?

Many of them indulge in degenerate things like alcohal drinking , indulging in premarital sex and other such stuffs.

Can these men be considered as brahmins ?

It is written in multiple places in different scriptures that a brahmin who indulge in degenerate stuffs , be considered as shudras .

Comment: Yes obviously. Most are just "birth-Brahminas" and reveling with pride and ego for that. The "Real ones" will mostly be 5 % of the total "birth-based Brahminas". In any way, everyone's born a Shudra  (... *janmo jayate* ...) , however, in present times:- Everyone's born Shudras and remain so - by our own "Karmas and gunas". Times are such. But remember: Being a Shudra is not a bad thing. Not being a "basic human" definitely is.

Comment: **Also,** Hi. Welcome to HSE.! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: @Vivikta Yeah but even some actual brahmins who were born brahmin and follows the duties of brahmin indulge in lying and cheating like this - youtube.com/watch?v=RxIkskloCRU 
He is Devki Nandan Thakur and he apparently lied to one person about a sanskrit shloka. 
How can such a person who lies and misguide people be considered as a brahmin ?

Comment: He didn't lie technically. He did beat around the bush to evade an accountable answer to the question posed. That's kind of not upto the mark.

Comment: @Vivikta - while 'janmo jayate shudra..' is true, it doesn't mean that everyone is the same level of shudra-tvam. if that were the cause, the "shudra" baby born to brahmins, and the "shudra" baby born to shudras will both be equally talented or eligible for all knowledge and rituals. It just means that birth is necessary but not sufficient to obtain the label of brahmana.

Comment: First of all, the present day living hardly supports the Vedic varnasystem. So it is outdated. Secondly, if one is born in Brahman family but does not follow Vedas etc, then why one is Shudra?? S/he can be Vaishya or Kshatriya, depending on the profession.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes indeed those Bramhins who don't study Vedas and engage in improper occupations are considered to be Shudras.

> But he who does not perform Sandhya Vandana standing in the morning,
> nor sitting in the evening, shall be excluded, like a Sudra, from all
> the duties and rights of an Dvija.(Manu 2.103)
>
> A brāhmaṇa who does not repeat the Gayatri mantra is more impure than
> even a śūdra and that brāhmaṇas who do not offer oblations to sacred
> fires, who are bereft of sandhya adoration and who do not study the
> Veda are all śūdras.(Parasara 8.24)
>
> A Brahmana who without studying the Vedas who labors for other things
> material wealth, position, adoration, and other opulences, becomes
> Sudra along with all his family members.(Manu 2.168)
>
> Those names which are applied to slaves and dogs and wolves, and
> (other) beasts, are applied to the Brahmin, who is engaged in pursuits
> that are improper for him.(MB Shanti 61.5)
>
> That wretched Brahmin, who neglects his duties, and whose behavior
> becomes corrupt, becomes a Śūdra. The Brahmin, who weds a Śūdra woman,
> who becomes  vile in conduct, or a dancer or a village servant, or
> does other improper acts, becomes a Śūdra. Whether he recites the
> Vedas or not, O king, if he does such improper acts, he becomes equal
> to a Śūdra, and on occasions of feeding, he should be assigned a place
> amongst Śūdras. (MB Shanti 62.4-5)

Comment: correct. birth alone is not sufficient. neither is study alone. nor rituals alone. but birth + study + rituals + Character - all 4 are necessary to be accepted with label of brahmana. Yudhishtira says the same in Yaksha Prashna.

Comment: Yudhishtira actually said that birth is not necessary at all - "A Sudra is not a Sudra by birth alone nor a Brahmana is Brahmana by birth alone. **He, it is said by the wise, in whom are seen those virtues is a Brahmana. And people term him a Sudra in whom those qualities do not exist, even though he be a Brahmana by birth... Manu has declared, that the mixed castes are to be regarded as better than the (other) classes, if having gone through the ceremonies of purification..  Whosoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous conduct, him have I, ere now, designated as a Brahmana.' "**

Comment: **"It is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of promiscuous intercourse among the four orders... Men belonging to all orders (promiscuously) beget offspring upon women of all the orders... And to this the Rishis have borne testimony by using as the beginning of a sacrifice such expressions as--of what caste so ever we may be, we celebrate the sacrifice. Therefore, those that are wise have asserted that character is the chief essential requisite."** - Yudhishtira does not care about birth at all. He knows that race-mixing is going on everywhere and designates anyone as Brahmin @mar

Comment: @R.Kaushik - it is almost impossible to ascertain a child's character. but shastras say brahamana children have to do upanayana at age 7, kshatriyas at age 11 etc. also, shudra children cannot (and do not) have upanayana done. does yudhishtira also mention how to ascertain a child's "character" by the time they start schooling ? You cannot read English translations and accept them as axioms. You have to listen to traditional upanyas from scholars who know how to interpret and read between the lines. The cases of non-brahmana birth having brahmana qualities are rare exceptions to the rule.

Comment: "Shastras" don't say that "some shastras" do say that the limit is 24. These are semi-sacred smritis. **Gautama Gryha Sutra and other ancient texts state that there is NO AGE RESTRICTION and anyone of ANY AGE can undertake Upanayanam when they feel they initiate their formal studies of the Vedas.** And yes it is possible to ascertain a child's character it happened to Jabala and many others. **There are countless people who changed their varna & varna-sankara in Hinduism even at an adult age** @mar

Comment: @R.Kaushik - Your definition of 'countless' seems to be a number than is less than 3 digits, out of the trillions of humans who have lived and died, all of whom followed the varna rules. You seem to be making a rule out of exceptions. Nobody ascertains a child's character to decide at what age upanayana rules apply to him. It is taken by birth alone.

Comment: @mar You are a smarta or Vaishnav reading personal opinions of very few people born in last 500-2000 years. **All trillions of Indians have been heavily mixed-race and this was going on in Mahabharata times. Almost all Brahmins at the time of Yudhishtir were mixed caste like you that's why Yudhishtir was designating everyone who was pure and virtuous as Brahmin without caring about birth.** And there is NO AGE RESTRICTION as per different shastras. **I will give you more than 3 from Mahabharata alone !!!**

Comment: **King Vitahavya becomes brahmin** IN FULL ADULTHOOD (MBH13, XXX), **Devapi, Vishwamitra, Sindhudwipa and others become Brahmins** IN FULL ADULTHOOD. (MBH9, 40) So these are multiple examples from only 2 sections of Mahabharata................. "Your definition of 'countless' seems to be a number than is less than 3 digits" -- Now you can apologize for this rude comment -- All non-Smriti scriptures contain **COUNTLESS SPECIFIC EXAMPLES** and say you can change or it is very common to change varna!! Lord Shiva also said this Mahabharata.

Comment: @R.Kaushik - you say "COUNTLESS SPECIFIC EXAMPLES" - and then you proceed to give countable examples. All these are exceptions. Just as news article never says 'Everything happened according to rules today, no murders, no crime'. They only report when a rule was broken. Shastras say the upper limit of 16,21,24 for upanyana. Nope, Yudhishtir did not designate everyone regardless of birth. There is a specific Yaksha Prashna question which people like to quote saying he didn't care about birth. But it has to be read with scholars opinion, not your own intellect.

Comment: @R.Kaushik Otherwise anyone can come up with their own theories. Of course, vishvamitra etc. became brahmins later due to INTENSE tapas. None of the shudras today are capable of that kind of penance. It's like saying "sachin tendulkar was 10th dropout, so you also don't need to attend 10th board exams". You cannot justify transgressing a rule due to exceptions.

Comment: @mar I can't count all the specific examples. **There are wayyyyyyy too many!!** I only gave OVER 3 because you rudely said there are "LESS THAN 3 DIGITS" to show that **you are 100% WRONG.** Yudhishthir already said that **you cannot tell anybody's caste!! Everyone was mixed caste** even back then thousands of years ago.... just like you are mixed race! You still haven't apologized for saying less than 3.

Comment: **All these are THE NORM... since almost EVERYONE was mixed caste** even in Yudhishtir's time!! This is also Shiva's command. There are also too many examples in Vaishnav Purans.  Jabala was the son of a prostitute with unknown father and he was declared Brahmin according to Upanishad itself and there are other examples in Vedas. **THE ONLY EXCEPTION TO ALL HINDU SCRIPTURES IS SMRITIS. Manu's words are TOTALLY WORTHLESS if they contradict what other scriptures and Shiva says !!**

Comment: @R.Kaushik - *"I only gave OVER 3 because LESS THAN 3 DIGITS"* - 3 digits means 100, not the number 3. *"since almost EVERYONE was mixed caste even in Yudhishtir's time"* - definitely not. because Arjuna specifically worries that the war will create many widows which will cause varna-sankara (caste mixing) in Gita 1st chapter. Again, you don't seem to understand the difference between a rule and an exception. See my Sachin Tendulkar example I gave earlier. Scriptures say "Accept whatever Manu says as Bhaishajam (i.e. medicine)."

Comment: @R.Kaushik -  "*just like you are mixed race*" - maybe you are mixed race, that's why you want to call everyone like that ? let's not go around casting accusations.

Comment: Well there are maximum only a few thousand characters in Hinduism, so 100 is a lot out of that!! Even **the author of Mahabharat & all Puraans was heavily mixed race!!** **There are only 3-5 main gods in Hinduism and if at least 2 of them are clearly saying you can change Varna**, anything Manu says in contradiction is totally worthless.

Comment: As I and Yudhishthir clearly said almost **everyone was mixed race.** Even Vyasa the author of MBH and all sacred Puraans was mixed race. You have not read Hindu scriptures. And I know for a fact that you are also mixed race just **like everyone else.** There is something called science which you have also not read. But maybe you have heard of the word science :)

Comment: Finally, as for Arjuna he was considered very foolish by Krishanji and himself was mixed caste (Ved Vyas & Ambalika from fathers side, mothers side was Yadava). So he was just talking trying to find excuse to not go to war. @mar Krishna does not affirm this anywhere. In fact, in Srimad Bhagavat Puraan there are **lots of people changing Varna.** This Puraan is considered the body of Krishna himself. You are going against the words of Shiva, Vishnu, Saptrishis, Vedic authors, Puranas, Itihasa, Vedas and secret scriptures..... so basically you are going against all of Hinduism except Smritis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125056/discussion-between-mar-and-r-kaushik).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As per Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa), most of the people in Kaliyuga will become shudra due to lack of knowledge and samskara.

> [ŚB 12.3.25](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/25/)
>
> तस्मिन् लुब्धा दुराचारा निर्दया: शुष्कवैरिण: ।
>  दुर्भगा
> भूरितर्षाश्च शूद्रदासोत्तरा: प्रजा: ॥ २५ ॥
>  tasmin lubdhā
> durācārā
>  nirdayāḥ śuṣka-vairiṇaḥ
>  durbhagā bhūri-tarṣāś ca
> śūdra-dāsottarāḥ prajāḥ
>
> > Translation:
> >
> > In the Kali age people tend to be greedy, ill-behaved and merciless, and they fight one another without good reason. **Unfortunate and obsessed with material desires, the people of Kali-yuga are almost all śūdras and barbarians.**

Comment: pls post the actual link of website url that you copy-pasted the above quote from.

Comment: @mar I am quoting verse from scriptures. There is no need to provide like no I think

Comment: Thanks .
Anything from Mahabharat which says similar thing ?

Comment: @SanatanDarshan - I can also quote something and say it is from scripture. There should be an independent way to verifying that what you wrote here and what is written in books are same. It doesn't cost much to simply post a link to the site from which you copy/pasted the above.

Comment: @mar sir I have the refrence. Now one can easily cross check from Bhagwatam.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan - did you physically type the above answer by looking at a book separately, or did you copy it from a pdf ? if pdf, pls link which site you downloaded the pdf. The whole point of this site is to give references to online material whenever possible.

Comment: I have edited the verse error. You cited wrong numbering of the verses. **It was 12:3:25 not 12:3:15**

Comment: @Vivikta thnx sir